# PHP SOAP fatal error message

Tags: php, magento, soap

My webserver has SOAP installed correctly (phpinfo has Soap Client/Server - Enabled).

I'm trying to create a SOAP request to a remote magento store, and I'm getting this error message:

```
[Mon Aug 29 20:13:59 2011] [error] [client 79.178.13.67] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [0] Unable to load Soap extension on the server in /home/example/public_html/mag/index.php:3

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('login', Array)
#1 /home/example/public_html/mag/index.php(3): SoapClient->login('user', 'pass')
#2 {main}\n  thrown in /home/example/public_html/mag/index.php on line 3
```

Code snippet here:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login('user','pass');
$attributeSets = $client->call($session,'product_attribute_set.list');
$set = current($attributeSets);
$sku = 'iphone-12345';
$imagePath="../image.jpg";
$newProductData = array(
'name'              => 'iPhone',
'websites'          => array(1),
'short_description' => 'short description',
'description'       => 'description',
'price'             => 150,
'status'            => '1',
);
$newImage = array(
'file' => array(
'name' => 'file_name',
'content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($imagePath)),
'mime'    => 'image/jpeg'
),
'label'    => 'Cool Image',
'position' => 0,
'types'    => array('image','small_image','thumbnail'),
'exclude'  => 0
);
$imageFilename = $client->call($sessionId, 'product_media.create', array($sku,$newImage));

$productId = $client->call($session,'product.create',array('simple', $set['set_id'],$sku,$newProductData));
echo $productId;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: check your server installation and config. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/20556/

Comment: @Marek Sebera - I'm running the script from a different server than my Magento server, does this affect anything? I know SOAP is installed correctly on the magento server as I get the correct XML response when I load the wsdl url

Comment: on another server means another `VirtualHost` or whole server (whole apache,httpd,nginx,... instance) ? the error says there is problem with loading SOAP extension, so there is probably some misconfiguration.

Comment: @Marek Sebera - completely different server.

Comment: so check your server config again, check startup messages of HTTP server (apache or whatever), check config in php.ini, httpd.conf,... check packages dependencies and restart your web server after successful updating your php* packages

Comment: @Marek Sebera Checked it all, unfortunately can't find any useful error message.. Google didn't help either.

Comment: Problem solved, please accept answer so anyone can know how you solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to updating Server side of WSDL (where SoapServer runs)

update :

- PHP
- PHP-SOAP

and dependencies ;-)

maybe outdated version of php (and/or soap) on server side